# How secure is Office.context.ui.messageParent?

Tags: office-js

Dialog API is really awesome when used with `Office.context.ui.messageParent()`. But I do not find any documentation where it is mentioned how and why regarding the security of this API. Only things I know that it can send a message to Parent:
1. The current page in the dialog box is in the same domain as the host page.
2. The Office JavaScript library is loaded on the page.

Can someone shed more light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently Desktop Dialog is created inside a secure sandbox with the restriction of Dialog URL to be in same domain, or if the domain is declared in the "AppDomains" in the manifest (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/appdomains). Both Dialog and the host Taskpane run inside their secure Sandbox. For API `Office.context.ui.messageParent()`, We use IPC to send message to the appropriate Host sandbox which fire it to the registered Event Handler. Here only the parent process (Host Sandbox) of the Dialog sandbox can receive the message which make it very secure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how it is getting handler behind the scenes, but my best guess would be that it is some sort of IPC (Inter Process Communication), where the child process send key/value pair to parent process, like in e.g. Electron. AFAIK only the parent process can receive the message, so it should be secure. Maybe 'Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT' can provide more insights.